# Was ist eine Community-Wiki-Frage?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

In einem Kommentar, den ich zu einer [von mir verfassten Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34755/1487) erhalten habe, wurde ich gefragt:

> Ist das vielleicht eine Community-Wiki-Frage, da mehrere Antworten gesucht werden?

Ich kann diese Frage nich beantworten, weil ich nicht weiß, was genau eine Community-Wiki-Frage ist. Ich weiß zwar, dass es solche Fragen gibt, habe aber keine Ahnung was eine Community-Wiki-Frage von einer normalen Frage unterscheidet. (Außer dass man in einer Community-Wiki-Frage weder die Frage noch die Antworten bewerten kann, was ich nicht gerade für vorteilhaft für irgendjemanden halte.) Ich habe auch keine Ahnung, wie man eine normale Frage zu einer Community-Wiki-Frage macht. Vor allem weiß ich nicht, wozu man das machen sollte.

Wenn ich hier in Meta nach »Community-Wiki« suche, finde ich zwar einige Fragen, aber erstens sind all diese Fragen (und ich vermute auch die Antworten) englisch, zweitens habe ich bei keiner Frage den Eindruck, dass mir das Lesen der Frage (samt Antwort) helfen könnte zu verstehen, was Community-Wiki-Fragen eigentlich sind.

Answer (score 6):

[Community-Wikis](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/255554) (CW) sind zunächst einmal für Antworten relevant. Technisch bestehen folgende Unterschiede zwischen einer CW-Antwort und einer normalen Antwort:

- 100 Reputationspunkte reichen aus, um die Antwort ohne Überprüfung durch andere editieren zu können.
- Up- und Downvotes sowie das Akzeptieren der Antwort haben keine Auswirkung auf die Reputationspunkte des Verfassers. Die Antwort zählt nicht für die Tag-Score des Verfassers.
- Badges, Bounties, u. Ä. funktionieren aber wie gehabt.

Solche Antworten sind insbesondere für Fälle gedacht, in denen eine Mitarbeit anderer Nutzer gewünscht wird, zum Beispiel [kleinere Listen](//german.stackexchange.com/a/20766/2594) (nach größeren Listen sollte gar nicht erst gefragt werden), [kanonische Fragen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357/2594) oder FAQs auf Meta (wie diese Antwort). Zum Beispiel habe ich diese Antwort zu einem Community-Wiki gemacht, damit andere Dinge leicht hinzufügen können, die sie für wesentlich halten oder die Antwort aktualisieren können, falls sich etwas an Community-Wikis ändert. CW-Antworten können auch dafür genutzt werden, absichtlich keine Reputationspunkte für eine Antwort zu bekommen, z. B., wenn man den Kommentar eines anderen in eine Antwort überführt hat, aber nicht voll hinter der Antwort steht.

Es gibt auch CW-Fragen, für die dasselbe gilt wie für CW-Antworten und deren Antworten automatisch zu Community-Wikis werden. Jeder Autor kann seine Antwort zu einem Community-Wiki machen, bei Fragen können das nur Moderatoren. Nur Moderatoren können diesen Status entfernen.

[Hier](//german.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=wiki%3ayes) ist eine Liste aller Community-Wikis auf der Hauptseite. Dabei ist zu beachten, dass es in der Vergangenheit eine Handvoll Mechanismen gab, Fragen und Antworten automatisch in Community-Wikis zu machen, für die dies aus heutiger Sicht keinen Sinn mehr ergibt. (Ihr dürft in diesem Fall gerne eine Flagge setzen, damit wir Moderatoren diesen Umstand beheben können.)